# Deserializing an object containing a list of int's

Tags: c#

I have a REST service returning XML of a serialized object containing a list of `int`. The object code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace All.Tms.Dto
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/All.Tms.Dto")]
    public class ReadSensorsForVehicleIdResponse
    {
        public List<int> sensorIdList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When this object is serialized the XML is generated and sent as:

```
<ReadSensorsForVehicleIdResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/All.Tms.Dto"      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><sensorIdList xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><a:int>107</a:int></sensorIdList></ReadSensorsForVehicleIdResponse>
```

The problem is that the int values are serialized as

```xml
<a:int>107</a:int>
```

this causes the deserializing of the object to fail. When I change

```xml
<a:int>107</a:int>
```

to

```xml
<int>107</int>
```

the object deserialize correctly. Is there any reason why the `int` values are serialized this way and how can I fix this problem?

Here is the code I use to deserialize

```xml
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));

        var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is easy to use

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); //or XDocument.Load(fileName)
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays";

var a = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "int")
            .Select(x => (int)x)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I added the code I use to deserialize to my question above. This code is use throughout my project and it will take alot of effort to change my objects to deserialize using the method you suggest.

Comment: I implemented you're suggested solution on the function deserializing the object I'm having trouble with. Thank you for the suggestion. +1

Answer (score 3):

It is an xml namespace that is being applied

```
xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
```

You will need to account for the namespace during your deserialization.

Comment: How do I do this given the object class above. I do not think xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" is the problem. As I said, when I remove the 'a:' characters within the int tags the object deserialize fine.

Comment: The a is being added because that namespace is being applied to the ints. xmlns:a
How are you attempting to deserialize?

Comment: Try modifying your deserialization method to handle xml namespaces using Linq to Xml as L.B has described.